# mysql check that user have more than N rows (pagination alternative)

Tags: mysql, pagination

I implementing a alternative to pagination.
I have a items table, each item have user owner.
I have index on user field.

Then user open page, I want to show first 10 items of this user
order by ids desc and a "more" button if more than 10 items exist.

User can click more and next 10 rows uploaded to the bottom and so on.

What is a more efficient way to check that more then N rows exists for check if I need to render "more" button.

I think about:

```
select 1 from items where user_id=%s and id<min_id limit 1;
```

there the min_id is the minimum id of prev. page.

is more effective solution exists?

Answer (score -1):

It may be more useful to have the order determined by some other factor than userid like date, name or something depending on the use case. The query & its syntax is not exactly clear but I understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe this would help you to get started.

```
     SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 20, 10
```

This essentially means display 10 records starting from the 20th record. You can couple this with ORDER BY user id DESC and code logic to modify the record number according to the page number.

Comment: I would appreciate comments on why it was down-voted to help improve my answer